# Find sibling with Javascript and Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hammer.js

I have made a simple system which detects double taps. I want to show a heart icon when someone double taps on an image, just like on Instagram.

This is what my code looks right now:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('snap_img');

[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    var hammertime = new Hammer(element),
    img_src = element.getAttribute('src');
    hammertime.on('doubletap', function(event) {
        alert(img_src); // this is to test if doubletap works
        // Some javascript to show the heart icon
    });
});
```

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="snap_item">
    <div class="snap_item_following_info">
        <img class="snap_item_following_img" src="res/stat/img/user/profile/small/1.fw.png" alt="@JohnDoe" />
        <a class="snap_item_following_name" href="#">@JohnDoe</a>
        <div class="snap_too">

        </div>
    </div>
    <img class="snap_img" src="res/stat/img/user/snap/43/2.fw.png" alt="@ErolSimsir" />
    <div class="like_heart"></div>
    <div class="snap_info">
        <div class="snap_text">
            LA is the shit...
            <a class="snap_text_hashtah" href="@">#LA_city_trip</a>
        </div>
        <div class="snap_sub_info">
            <span class="snap_time">56 minutes ago</span>
            <div class="like inactive_like">
                <div class="like_icon"></div>
                <div class="like_no_active">5477</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when the element 'snap_img' is double tapped, I need to get the element 'like_heart' which is one line below the snap_img element. How do I get that sibling element and fade it in with JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    var hammertime = new Hammer(element),
    img_src = element.getAttribute('src');
    hammertime.on('doubletap', function(event) {
        alert(img_src); // this is to test if doubletap works
        $(element).next().text('♥').hide().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

P.S. I've added that heart text, since the sibling was empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The sibling is an empty div, but has a background image (a sprite with a heart icon). Your solution works like a charm, so thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: Of course! I always have to wait a few minutes until I can accept answers. I'll do it right away!

Answer (score 1):

On the event handler, i would do `$(element).parent().find('.like_heart').fadeIn();` So the code is not dependant on the element ordering.

(To clarify to selector: take the parent element which is the `div.snap_item` and find an element with class `like-heart` inside it)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've fixed the problem with Amit's solution (see his answer below).